# Qiskit: QAOAnsatz circuit with custom Hamiltonian

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, vqe, optimization

I am trying to implement the Quantum Approximate Optimization Ansatz by creating a parametrized subcircuit

$$V (α) = e^{−iH_M α_1} e^{−iH_D b_1} ... e^{−iH_M α_n} e^{−iH_D b_n}$$
with the custom driver hamiltonian $H_M = \mathbb{I} - \left|b \right> \left< b\right|$, where $\left| b \right>= U \left| 0 \right>$ is a random normalized state, and the default $H_M$ mixer hamiltonian of the original paper.

I have a problem feeding my hamiltonian to the [`QAOAAnsatz`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.QAOAAnsatz.html) as it asks an `OperatorBase` class for input.

**How do I construct the `Operator` object for `QAOAAnsatz` or how do I create a custom QAOA circuit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $U$ is given as a quantum circuit:

```
U = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
```

Then to get the state vector $\left| b \right>$ we can use `Statevector.evolve()` method<sup>[[1]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.evolve.html)</sup>

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

zero = Statevector.from_label('0'*num_qubits)
b = zero.evolve(U)
```

The method `Statevector.to_operator()`<sup>[[2]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.to_operator.html)</sup> converts a state to a rank-1 projector operator. So we can construct an `OperatorBase` instance for $H_D = \mathbb{I} - \left|b \right> \left< b\right|$ as follows:

```
from qiskit.opflow import I
from qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops import PrimitiveOp

projector_op = PrimitiveOp(b.to_operator())
cost_operator = (I^num_qubits) - projector_op
```

Finally,

```
ansatz = QAOAAnsatz(cost_operator)
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work so far. I have a question though: when I do `ansatz.parameters` it returns a list of `2n=4` parameters as expected (`n=2` in my case). But when I decompose and draw the circuit two extra parameters are shown: `-0.875(t[0]+t[2])` with the indication of `Global Phase`. When I use the QAOA as a subcircuit to `qc` and do `qc.parameters` I get indeed 6 parameters instead of 4. What is going on?

Comment: As it seems the `t` parameters are present only in the transpiled circuit.